# input text of text area after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the input text of a textarea to the console. 
The user would type a message then click a button and then the text would get printed to the console...

Here's my HTML:

```
<form action='/send_message' method='POST'>
        <textarea name='message' id='message_box'></textarea>
        <input name='receiver_id' type='text' id='number' style="display: none" value="{{info[0][0]}}">
        <button id='btn' class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Message {{info[0][2]}}</button>
    </form>
```

and here is the JS:

```
        var message = $('textarea#message_box').val();
        var button = document.getElementById('btn');

        button.addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log(message)
        });
```

The problem is that I get an empty message in the console no matter if the area is empty or containing text.
I tried various combinations of val(), text, innerHTML but I pretty much always get the same empty output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the value of textarea when the button is clicked so assign the `message` variable inside the event listener. Because we want to get the value of textarea each time button is clicked.

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var message = $('textarea#message_box').val();
    console.log(message)
});
```